# Variable scope problems C#

Tags: c#, variables, static, scope

I'm learning C# and i'm having problems with variable scope in my simple console program.

The program runs perfectly so far except I know I will encounter issues when trying to reference variables previously instantiated.

I have tried to change methods from static to non static and also applied public/private access but to no avail.

I just need a nudge in the right direction, hope someone can help!

The error message i'm getting is :

> Error  1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.game()'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        int numberToGuess;
        int numberGuessed;
        int triesRemaining;

        public void game()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("           ==Welcome to Guess My Number== \n");
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1: Please enter your number to guess between 1 and 20: \n");
            numberToGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2, please enter your first guess, you have 7 tries: \n");
            numberGuessed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (numberGuessed == numberToGuess)
            {
                correct();
            }
            else
            {
                incorrect();
            }

        }

        public void correct()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, the number was in fact " + numberToGuess);
        }

        public void incorrect()
        {

        }


        static void  Main(string[] args)
        {
            game();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your Main Method is a static method,others method not static.
add static at varibles/method will be fine.

Comment: I wish this hadn't been put on hold, frankly it's as clear as it can be what you're having struggling with. I explained in detail about your issue and how to solve it but to sum it up in comment form so I can actually get it to you now is essentially change: `game();` to `new Program().game();` and your program should function correctly.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked perfectly! Now I just need to research why Program() was needed. I know i'm going behind my understanding at the moment but just wanted to try this challenge while im working through my textbook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*instance* members (those not marked with the `static` keyword) exist once per object instance. **Every** instance of an object gets its own copies of them.

*static* members, on the other hand, exist once for the entire class and are shared by *all* object instances.

So, If you've got a class:

```
class Foo
{
   public static int Alpha { get ; set ; }
   public        int Bravo { get ; set ; }
}
```

No matter how many instances of your `Foo` class are created, there is only one instance of `Alpha`. Any instance method or property can access a static member directly.

Instance members, since they exist on a **per-instance** basic, require an object instance to reference them. If you add some methods to the `Foo` class:

```
public static int DoSomething()
{
   return Alpha * 3 ;
}
```

is perfectly valid — the method is static and the member is static. Ditto for an instance method:

```
public int DoSomethingElse()
{
  return Alpha * 3 ;
}
```

Something like this will fail:

```
public static int AndNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent()
{
  return Alpha * 3 + Bravo ;
}
```

`Bravo` can't be referenced here without a *reference* to an instance of `Foo`. This will work however:

```
public static int AndNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent( Foo instance )
{
  return Alpha * 3 + instance.Bravo ;
}
```

As will this:

```
public int AndNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent()
{
  return Alpha * 3 + Bravo ;
}
```

Since the method is non-static (an instance method), it has an implicit reference (`this`) to its instance of `Foo`. The above is exactly equivalent to

```
public int AndNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent()
{
  return Alpha * 3 + this.Bravo ;
}
```

In your case, you could instantiate the class `Program` in your `Main()` method:

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{
  Program p = new Program() ;
  p.game() ;
  return ;
}
```

Or you could mark your methods `game()`, `correct()` and `incorrect()` as `static`, just as the `Main()` method is marked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: SuperB explanation for eternally confused creatures like me...thanks

Comment: Perfect! Very well explained! I've gone on to finish the program but I am going to experiment with a whole lot of features and push myself as far as I can go!

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods/fields belong to the user-defined type, not the instance.

For example, if you look at this piece of code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

the `Foo()` method, is not accessed from an instance of `MyClass`. Since it is `static`, you access it from the user-defined type itself. Ex:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass.Foo();
    }
}
```

Since `Main()` is `static`, you can only reference static methods or variables inside it (this excludes methods referenced from local instance variables).

In your code, the method `game()` and the fields/methods being called/invoked by game are not `static`, therefore you would only be able to access it via an object instance. Of course, making `game()` and all the other fields/methods `static` would result in a working piece of code.

For more information on `static` types, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have gone on to complete the methods and it seems to be working great!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

 namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
public class Program
{
    int numberToGuess;
    int numberGuessed;
    int triesRemaining = 7;
    string playAgain;
    string player1, player2;

    public void game()                                                                                                              //Initiates the game instance
        {
            Console.WriteLine("           ==Welcome to Guess My Number== \n");
            Console.WriteLine(" Player 1, Please enter your name: \n");
            player1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("                      ==Guess My Number== \n");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + player1 + " : Please enter your number to guess between 1 and 20: \n");
            numberToGuess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("           ==Guess My Number== \n");
            Console.WriteLine(" Player 2, Please enter your name: \n");
            player2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + player2 + " please enter your first guess, you have 7 tries: \n");
            numberGuessed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (numberGuessed == numberToGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, the number was in fact " + numberToGuess);
                newGame();
            }
            else
            {
                incorrect();
            }

        }

    public void incorrect()                                                                                                         //Method for dealing with incorrect answers
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            triesRemaining--;
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, you have " + triesRemaining + " tries remaining \n");
            Console.WriteLine(player2 + ", please enter your next guess: \n");
            numberGuessed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (numberGuessed == numberToGuess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, the number was in fact " + numberToGuess);
                newGame();
            }
            else { 
                //Do nothing
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("You have used up all your tries! You have failed. The number was: " +numberToGuess + "\n");
        newGame();
    }                                                      //Method for dealing with incorrect answers

    public void newGame()                                                                                                           //Method that gives the user the option to start a new game instance
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? Type yes or no: \n");
        playAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        playAgain = playAgain.ToLower();
        if (playAgain == "yes")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            game();
        }
        else if (playAgain == "y")
        {
            game();
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
    }                                                        

   static void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().game();

    }
}
}
```